# Graphing program cant get x,y from list

Tags: python

I am making a sort of graph for a text based game and I have some code for a part of the graphing. I want to add the places the player has been to a list of x, y coordinates so I can draw it later.

```
objects = {"Player":[2,2]}
clearedSpaces = []

def changePos(name, newx, newy):
    objects[name][0] += newx
    objects[name][1] += newy
    global clearedSpaces
    clearedSpaces.append([objects[name][0],objects[name][1]])

#####Each of these makes the player go up one space#####
changePos("Player",1,0)
changePos("Player",1,0)
changePos("Player",1,0)
changePos("Player",1,0)


print clearedSpaces
for space in clearedSpaces:

    ########Here is where the problem seems to occur########
    print(clearedSpaces[space][0])
    print(clearedSpaces[space][1])
    print space
```

I put a comment above where the problem seems to be. also heres the error I get:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 19, in 
TypeError: list indices must be integers, not list

Comment: Whoever was trying to edit the question: Please do not try to fix the code in the question and try to cram an explanation of the problem into an edit comment. That's what answers are for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`clearedSpaces` is a list of lists of integers.

So `for space in clearedSpaces` means that each `space` is a list of integers.

So `clearedSpaces[space]` is trying to use a list as an index. Hence the `TypeError: list indices must be integers, not list`.

---

What you almost certainly wanted was just `space` itself:

```
for space in clearedSpaces:
    print(space[0])
    print(space[1])
    print(space)
```

---

If you really *do* need the index for some reason, use `enumerate`:

```
for i, space in enumerate(clearedSpaces):
    print(clearedSpaces[i][0])
```

But in this example, that isn't useful, because you already have `space`, which is the same thing as `clearedSpaces[i]` (but more readable).